# Change 'src' attribute of an image from php variable which was set by a mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

basically i want to change the 'src' attribute of an image by fetching data from a mysql database.

I have a query.php file and the index.html file.

The php script in the query.php document works fine and gets the correct data, which is now saved in a php variable called

> $newimagesrc

Now how can i change the 'src' of the image with javascript(i guess)? Do i have to implement everything in one document? The idea is to show the image and by clicking on a button the page reloads and a new image is displayed.

Thank you!

my html document:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" alt=changingimage">
</body>
</html>
```

my php document:

```
   // mysql_connect stuff right here

  // QUERY FOR NEW IMAGE
 $imagequery = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysql_query($imagequery);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
$newimagesrc = "$row->imageurl";
}
```

Comment: First you have to post some code. YOu know, just to let us know how things works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code to implement it:

On the user side, you make an XHR(I'll use a jquery XHR since it's less lines to demonstrate, but you can use any XHR wrapper or even the vanilla object itself)

```
$.get('/path/to/query_script.php', { perhaps: 'you', need: ['some', 'data', 'sent', 'to', 'the', 'server'] }, function (data) {
   // Select the image somehow and apply the data you just received
   $('#myImage').attr('src', data);
});
```

And on the php side you'd have something like this:

```
// Your code to fetch the source here..
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
echo(json_encode($newimagesrc)); // Encodes your data in a json format and hopefully sends that as *the only thing* in the response
```

The general thing to realise here is that you are directing communication between two different actors - a browser, which is running your javascript code, and your server, which is running your php code. The browser needs to send a request(here solved by using XHR) to your server, and the server must return some useful response(here realised by returning the image source in a convenient json format). You could expand this to return more than just one string(you can serialize arrays and whole objects in a json format), and consequently, using the data on the client side.

Comment: Ok thank you. I already thought that i would need ajax. So to sum this up, i need an ajax call which calls the php document and puts the php variable value into 'data'. Afer that the data can be used to change it with jquery?

Comment: when you look at the php code above from my post. Would the $newimagesrc then be in the data object?

Comment: You're mistaking how the communication flow goes, again. To the client side, where your javascript is being executed, your php code *does not exist*. All the client side knows is that when it makes a request to a certain url (`http://www.example.com/some/path/query.php`), it gets a certain response(in this case, some json formatted data). The client performs the request, gets a response, and then you land in the `function (data) { ... }` part of the javascript code, where you can access whatever data the server sent you.

Comment: Similarly, to your server, there is no "javascript code doing stuff". All your server knows is that something made a request, perhaps sending some data along with it - and your server does what it does(querying the database and whatnot), and eventually needs to return a *response* - in this case, some json-formatted data which the requester can hopefully use.

Comment: thanks a lot i figured it out by using an ajax tutorial :) thanks for the right direction

Comment: Awesome, I've been trying to find a decent ajax tutorial to link here for a while, you might want to edit your post with what you found so it's useful for people that stumble on the question.

Comment: I used this one: simple and no unnecessary code http://www.cleverweb.nl/php/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial/.

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery set image src by

```
$("#img_tag_id").attr("src","PATH_FROM_DB_WHICH_DISPLAYS_IMAGE")
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1302/)

Comment: what would i put into the second ""? Just the php variable? I think i have to change it to a js variable or not?

Comment: i edited..forgot to put that..you have to put the url of image from where it can be displayed

Comment: What does PATH mean? Can you give me an example from my code above?

Comment: The path is the url or address at which the image canbe downloaded.it can be relative or absolute e.g. /img/image.jpg or http://www.example.com/img/image.jpg